# Botão Excluir não funciona

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código para cadastrar e excluir registro pelo ajax, o botão Cadastrar Funciona mais quando clico em Excluir, retorna

> Ajax Submit Failed deletar convidado

Mas está excluindo do banco já.

Poderim me dizer onde está o erro?

```
<form url="cadastra_convidado.php" method="post" id="reg-form_2" autocomplete="off" style="border:none;">
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="" placeholder="Digite o Nome do Convidado"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Digite o email do Convidado">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar convidado</button>
</form>

<form url="deletar_convidado.php" method="post" id="reg-form_3" autocomplete="off" style="border:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="deletar_convidado" id="deletar_convidado" value="<?php echo $row_convidados['id']; ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:20px;width: 100%;" type="submit">Exlcluir</button>
</form>
<div id="form-content_2"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#reg-form_2').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'cadastra_convidado.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#form-content_2').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('#form-content_2').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            });
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
        });
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#reg-form_3', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'deletar_convidado.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#form-content_2').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('#form-content_2').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            });
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert('Ajax Submit Failed deletar convidado ...');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas a enviar dois POST'S

Tenta remover o POST feito pelo **form**

No botão excluir muda o type de submit para button e atribui um id

[Segue este exemplo do w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

No meu caso uso o [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), extensão do google para testar requisições GET & POST, esta extensão poderá te ajudar